# visibility guarantees of synchronized and volatile

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility, synchronized, java-memory-model

I have found that I and my colleague have different understanding of visibility guarantes.

we have same volatile understanding and think that:
**Value written to volatile variable will be visible at once**

about syncronized:

my opinion:
We can quarantee that changes made in syncronized section become visible after syncronized section exit but **only in syncronized section by same monitor**.

I have this opinion because in jls written:

> An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that
>   monitor.

colleague opinion:
We can quarantee that changes made in syncronized section become visible after syncronized section exit.

What the right opinion?

Please provide right happens before

Comment: Personally me, I do not understand what do you mean by *" visible after syncronized section termination but only in syncronized section by same monitor"*. Seems that your colleague has more proper understanding

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in the Java Language Specification.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/  Showing your colleague the relevant section from the JLS ought to be way more convincing than showing him/her some opinion that you found on the internet.

Comment: As far as I know, the visibility is a consequence of memory barriers. Each time you enter a synchronized block, a read barrier is triggered, causing the executing thread to invalidate its local memory and read all variables from the main memory. Exiting a synchronized block triggers a write barrier, which flushes out all the changes from the local memory to the main memory. Same goes for volatile variables as well. In short, your colleague is right.

Comment: @james large I agree but you can treat it differently

Comment: @MDSayemAhmed, that would be an implementation detail.  Sometimes it's important to know what some particular implementation actually does do.  Other times, it's important to know what all valid implementations are _guaranteed_ to do.

Comment: From the JLS section 17.4.4, "An unlock action on monitor _m_ synchronizes with all subsequent lock actions on _m_."  From that, you can only infer that synchronization happens when both threads are operating on the _same_ lock object.

Comment: As per the duplicate's Brian Goetz's answer, people being correct here are james large and gstackoverflow. Congratulations to the winners.

Comment: @jameslarge: cool! Thanks for clarifying and thus eliminating one of my confusions!

Comment: @MD Sayem Ahmed: even if we assume that the barriers were always present (and not elided by the JVM where possible), they were only effective, if the reading thread passes its read barrier *after* the writing thread passed its write barrier. But since threads synchronizing on different objects have no enforced ordering but still run concurrently, you are placing bets on the scheduler. Likewise, if two threads access a volatile variable, they can only determine their ordering by checking the variable’s value. That only works, if it is the same variable. The optimizer adds fuel to the fire…